# Datetime type X axis on MS Chart control without showing weekends

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm using the MS Chart control in .Net 4 to display 4 data series, the X axis is set to datetime type.

with the interval set to days the graph includes weekend even though no weekend dates are included in the data.

All the series except one have the same date points, the exception is a projection line that starts on the last date and continues for a number of working days (excludes weekends).

How can remove the display of weekends (or dates that have no value) from the chart for all series?

this is a winforms .Net 4.0 Application.

```
 foreach (var series in chart2.Series)
   {
       series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
       series.BorderWidth = 5;
       series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
       // I Tried this to remove weekends but it results in the graph showing a big red X
       series.IsXValueIndexed = true; 
   }
```

Edit with Code to reproduce my issue below:

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;

        Series test1 = new Series("Test1");
        test1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            //skip the weekend
            if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday") dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday") dt = dt.AddDays(1);

            test1.Points.AddXY(dt.Date, i);
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            i++;
        }

        chart1.Series.Add(test1);

        Series test2 = new Series("Test2");
        test1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            //skip the weekend
            if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday") dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday") dt = dt.AddDays(1);

            test2.Points.AddXY(dt.Date, i);
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            i++;
        }

        chart1.Series.Add(test2);

        foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
        {
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            series.BorderWidth = 5;
            series.IsXValueIndexed=true;
        }
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the x-values as `DateTime`, which is what you should do. But by default this means the all x-values are positionend proportionally, as one usually wants them to be.

But your case is an exception, that is even mentioned in the documentation of the [`Series.IsXValueIndexed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> All data points in a series use sequential indices, and if this
>   property is true then data points will be plotted sequentially,
>   regardless of their associated X-values. This means that there will be
>   no "missing" data points.
>
> For example, assume there are three (3) data points in a series having
>   X-values of 1, 2 and 4. If this property was false, there would be a
>   data point missing at the X-axis location labeled "3". However, if you
>   set this property to true, the three data points will be plotted at
>   points 1, 2, and 4, sequentially, and there will be no missing data
>   point. The X-axis location labeled "3" will not appear on the chart.
>
> **This is useful** when you do not want to have missing data points for
>   intervals that you know you will not have data for, **such as weekends**.

**Note however:**

> If you are displaying multiple series and at least one series uses
>   indexed X-values, then all series must be **aligned** — that is, have the
>   same number of data points—and the corresponding points must have the
>   same X-values.

So you were correct in using this property, however, most likely, your series were not fully **aligned**.

To make sure they are one often can make use of one of the `Chart.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints` overloads. Unfortunately they all work with a fixed `Interval`, not with a template `Series`.

So you will need to makes sure to add one [Empty DataPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) wherever your data are missing a value in a `Series`. If the data are databound you will have to do that in the `DataSource`!

Comment: Hi Taw, thanks for your reply, I have added above code to show my issue! If I comment out all the test2 stuff test1 works with both in I get the red X.

from the above do I need to add an empty data points for all the dates in test one and test2 to both series?

Comment: Yes, that is if you actually __wanted__ to keep counting up `dt` without resetting it between the two series..!?

Comment: yes this is just an example for real I plot a sequence and then add a projection which will extend the line.

How do I say add all the empty data point to each as they are beyond the beginning of test2 and after the end of test1?

could you show me how i would do that?

Comment: That bit will be somewhat tedious as is involves looping over all series twice and all points to find the missing points.. Do you want to get rid of only the gaps at the weekends or also the workdays that happen to not have data at any series? In the 1st case adding a dummy sereis with a dummy point for ech workday would make things a lot easier, since you would only loop over the points of that series and the other series..

Comment: Sorry I think I'm getting confused on what and how to do this, Sorry!
in answer to your questions I'm just looking to remove weekends all other days will have data points within their ranges.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663244/how-to-align-indexed-series-in-a-chart/38663245#38663245) for a function that will align all your series!