# How to align indexed Series in a Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart, series

When setting a `Series` to be *indexed* by setting the [`Series.IsXValueIndexed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to `true` the chart requires all `Series` to be *aligned*:

> If you are displaying multiple series and at least one series uses
>   indexed X-values, then all series must be aligned — that is, have the
>   same number of data points—and the corresponding points must have the
>   same X-values.

How can you add the necessary `Emtpy DataPoints` to the slots they are missing in, in any of the `Series`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This routine first collects all values in all `Series` in a collection of `doubles`.

Then it loops over all `Series` and over all values and inserts the missing empty `DataPoints`:

```
void AlignSeries(Chart chart)
{
    var allValues = chart.Series.SelectMany(s => s.Points)
                          .Select(x=>x.XValue).Distinct().ToList();
    foreach (Series series in chart.Series)
    {
        int px = 0;    //insertion index
        foreach(double d in allValues )
        {
            var p = series.Points.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.XValue == d);
            if (p == null)  // this value is missing
            {
                DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(d, double.NaN);
                dp.IsEmpty = true;
                series.Points.Insert(px, dp);
            }
            px++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the code assumes ..

- that your x-values are correctly set, i.e. they were added as `numbers` or `DateTimes`. If you added them as `strings` they all are `0` and indexing makes no sense.
- that the `DataPoints` were added in **ascending** order. This is not always the case, especially when plotting `LineCharts`. However indexing these makes no sense either.

Also note that you can set several options of how to treat `Empty DataPoints` in a `Series` by setting properties in the [`Series.EmptyPointStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.emptypointstyle(v=vs.110).aspx), which is derived from [`DataPointCustomProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So you could set their `Color` like this:

```
 someSeries.EmptyPointStyle.Color = Color.Red;
```